# Docker daemon error response: error while creating mount - permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aws-sdk

I am having problem using AWS credentials from ~/.aws on Windows machine, with either docker or docker-compose.

```
>docker run --rm -v c:/Users/Zaak/.aws:/root/.aws:ro alpine ls -a /root/.aws
>docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Users/Zaak/.aws': mkdir /host_mnt/c/Users/Zaak/.aws: permission denied.
```

When I copy the .aws outside of the user folder it works perfectly.
I can even mount the User/Zaak folder, but not the containing folders.

After checking permissions on folder, parent folder, deleting and recreating and even renaming it, I am at a complete loss as to what permission needs to be set where to allow this.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On pure blind luck the answer was to add permission for group: (MACHINENAME)\Users

Comment: This is very odd, i have ran into this issue after months of using it perfectly fine. I already have that permission applied.